# OpenGL/Libgdx : Square grid rendering optimization

Tags: optimization, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

My game background rendering takes 1/4 of all the rendering duration I've been trying to improve it, but still I don't think it's normal that it takes so long knowing how simple it is :

The background is a square grid (like a chessboard) where every square has its own color, which changes every frame, The squares y position changes every frame too, but not the x position

Here is my main render function

```
public void main.render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    final float deltaS = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    background.update(deltaS);
    updateTheGame(deltaS);

    background.render();

    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    renderTheGame(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();

}
```

Here is the background's mesh declaration

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, nbVertices, nbIndices,
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorUnpacked, 3, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE));
```

Here is the background update function (Called every frame, before render())
 (This is not the one I want to optimize)

```
void background.update(float deltaS) {
    for (BGSquareRow row : squareRows)
        row.update(deltaS);
    setupVerticesArray();
    mesh.updateVertices(0, verticesArray);
}


private final Color tmpColor = new Color();

private void setupVerticesArray() {
    int index = 0;
    for (BGSquareRow row : squareRows) {
        final float y0 = row.y;
        final float y1 = row.y + squareSize;
        for (int i=0; i<nbSquareX; i++) {
            row.getSquareColor(i, tmpColor);
            final float x0 = squareXs[i];
            final float x1 = squareXs[i+1];
            verticesArray[index++] = x0;
            verticesArray[index++] = y0;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.r;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.g;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.b;
            verticesArray[index++] = x1;
            verticesArray[index++] = y0;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.r;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.g;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.b;
            verticesArray[index++] = x1;
            verticesArray[index++] = y1;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.r;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.g;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.b;
            verticesArray[index++] = x0;
            verticesArray[index++] = y1;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.r;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.g;
            verticesArray[index++] = tmpColor.b;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the background rendering function, called every frame after background.update() (This is the way too costy one)

```
 void background.render() {
      shaderProgram.begin();
      shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", parent.uiCamera.combined);
      mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
      shaderProgram.end();
 }
```

I tried to put only the minimum required to understand my issue, so if I forgot something important, please tell me

I have some ideas of optimization, but I don't know how to do it :

- Would it be possible to draw the background's mesh on the main spriteBatch? This would lead to 1 draw call in the main.render() function instead of 2 if I am right
- Is it possible to update only the y, red, blue and green values in the mesh vertice buffer? I found ways to update a part of the vertice buffer, but only if it's a continuous part
- Is there any possible optimization for the verticesArray setup?

(I also tried to use ColorPacked for the vertice buffer, but it wasn't better)

Comment: How many rows/columns are there?

Comment: There are 17 rows of 10 squares! It fills the screen

Comment: And do you know if you are fill rate limited or CPU limited, or what? This looks really trivial, so if you are needing to optimize it, there may be some serious issue that is in code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your mesh with use of [meshParts](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/MeshPart.html), where each `meshPart` will represent single grid square. Then you can color each of squares with different color by using a GLSL shader. That should minimize your CPU work time and will utilize GPU power.

[Here's an example of colorizing shader with libGDX.](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-materials-with-libgdx/) `MeshPart` render method supports passing `ShaderProgram` as a parameter and can contain specific material.